# Start google vm instance from my api-url and run specific commands by specific URL-api endpoints

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-platform, debian

New to GCP and NodeJS. Please bear with my lack of expertise.

My google VM instance is Debian

Api-endpoint 1

```
mynodejsserverongooglevminstance.com/api/startservice
```

This would run some commands on Debian VM instance

```
screen
node start.js
node index.js
```

API-endpoint 2

```
mynodejsserverongooglevminstance.com/api/stopservice
node stop.js
```

stopservice endpoint would run some more commands...

Basically I am asking what would be the best go-at-it for this?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm going to use the Express HTTP library

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const AuthValidator = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.headers['X-Secret-Code'] === 'some_super_secret_password') return next();
  
  return res.status(400).end('Bad Authorization');
  
}

app.get('/api/startservice', (req, res) => {
  exec('screen && node start.js && node index.js', (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Fail to start Node app: ${error}`);
      return res.status(500).end(error.message);
    }
    res.status(201).end(stdout);
  });
});

app.get('/api/stopservice', (req, res) => {
  exec('node stop.js', (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Fail to stop Node app: ${error}`);
      return res.status(500).end(error.message);
    }
    res.status(201).end(stdout);
  });
});
```

And once the client perform a `GET` request to the `/api/startservice` endpoint, the Node app will help execute three of those commands

Same goes for the `/api/stopservice`, once this endpoint get trigger, the Node app will execute the `stop.js` script

Comment: Solution for communicating with the GCP vm-instance?

Comment: Using their official build GCP CLI tool